# Kerberos: HTTP/computer.domain@DOMAIN vs HTTP/computer@DOMAIN as service principal name

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

Is there any simple explanation about which is correct? I suppose both can used, just like I can access computer on a network via 'computer' and 'computer.domain'.

Maybe there're different correct answers depending on domains?

Is this dependent on Active Directory (Windows Server) domain controller version? (As you can see I'm particularly interested in Windows domain usecases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is used when DNS will resolve the FQDN the second one is used when WINS will resolve the short hostname. IMHO, disable WINS and do not rely on this relic at all. Use DNS only.